# Implement a struct type on top of void *

Tags: c, types, casting, c11

Simple sanity check question here. The underlying requirement is to put two flexible array members in a struct to reduce the number of calls to malloc for performance reasons.

Given that a struct instance is a block of aligned memory containing a number of fields at constant offsets, can one implement functionality semantically equivalent to a struct by writing the offset calculations and casting?

```
void f()
{
  typedef struct
  {
    double x;
    char y;
    int32_t foo;
    double z;
  } equivalent;
  equivalent * e = malloc(sizeof(equivalent));
  free(e);

  static_assert(sizeof(equivalent) == 24,"");
  char* memory = malloc(24);
  double* x    = (double*)  ( 0 + memory);
  char* y      = (char *)   ( 8 + memory);
  int32_t* foo = (int32_t*) (12 + memory);
  double* z    = (double*)  (16 + memory);
  free(memory);
}
```

Keeping the alignment / offset calculations consistent is tedious, but assuming the type is opaque anyway the client code doesn't have to see any of that. Similarly the syntactic overhead is hidden.

I've read through the aliasing rules as clarified by C11 (the "effective type" part) and think I'm in the clear there.

Is this fair game? I thought I'd seek a second opinion prior to writing a lot of very dull code.

Cheers

edit: As a response to Jonathan Leffler, this is a quick & dirty sketch of how I intend to put a couple of arrays of runtime determined length into the single block of memory.

I prefer storing an integer which is used to calculate the location of the array, as opposed to storing a pointer which is already aimed at the array, because it makes copying the structure simpler. Storing appropriately initialised pointers and relocating them on copy is probably faster though.

```
void* g(uint64_t N_first, uint64_t N_second)
{
  // desired representation:                                                                                                                                                     
  // uint64_t N_first;                                                                                                                                                           
  // int32_t first[N_first];                                                                                                                                                     
  // uint64_t N_second;                                                                                                                                                          
  // double second[N_second];                                                                                                                                                    
  // this function doesn't populate the arrays, only                                                                                                                             
  // allocates storage and sets up the length fields                                                                                                                             

  uint64_t bytes_for_lengths = 16;

  char* bytes = malloc(bytes_for_lengths + bytes_for_first(N_first) +
                       bytes_for_second(N_second));

  uint64_t* ptr_N_first = get_N_first(bytes);
  *ptr_N_first = N_first;

  uint64_t* ptr_N_second = get_N_second(bytes);
  *ptr_N_second = N_second;

  return (void*)bytes;
}

// I haven't decided how best to factor out the field access
// and associated functions yet, so this is not optimal

uint64_t* get_N_first(void* vdata)
{
  char* data = (char*)vdata;
  return (uint64_t*)(data + 0);
}
int32_t* get_first(void* vdata)
{
  char * data = (char*)vdata;
  return (int32_t*)(data + 8);
}
uint64_t bytes_for_first(uint64_t N_first)
{
  // first is an int32_t                                                                                                                                                         
  // the next field needs to be 8 byte aligned                                                                                                                                   
  uint64_t bytes = 4 * N_first;
  if (bytes % 8 != 0)
    {
      bytes += 4;
    }
  return bytes;
}

uint64_t* get_N_second(void* vdata)
{
  uint64_t n_first = *get_N_first(vdata);
  uint64_t first_bytes = bytes_for_first(n_first);
  char* data = (char*)vdata;
  return (uint64_t*)(data + 8 + first_bytes);
}
double* get_second(void* vdata)
{
  char * data = (char*)vdata;
  uint64_t n_first = *get_N_first(vdata);
  uint64_t first_bytes = bytes_for_first(n_first);
  return (double*)(data + 8 + first_bytes + 8);
}
uint64_t bytes_for_second(uint64_t N_second)
{
  // second is a double                                                                                                                                                          
  return 8 * N_second;
}
```

Comment: What you're up to here is fine.  What isn't clear is how you're going to adapt this to achieve 'two flexible array members in a struct'.  You can't do it directly; you can achieve approximately the result with care by using two pointers in the structure and contiguously allocated memory, but you do have to be careful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. I've added a sketch of how I intend to adapt this.  It's obviously fairly error prone, but that's solvable if C is willing to play nice.

Comment: How exactly is this beneficial after the code is compiled? I would assume that any half decent compiler would generate more or less the same code, or at least just as fast code for accessing steuct members or doing manual offsets. But I might just fail to see the point here

Comment: `uint64_t bytes_for_lengths = 16;` <--- DO NOT do that, you don't want to have this ticking time bombs lying around everywhere. Instead, use `2 * sizeof(uint64_t)` and the like.

Comment: As a general rule, you'll be better off avoiding `void *` in the interfaces.  You can pass any pointer type at all to a function that accepts `void *`; you get no type checking.  You'd do better with an opaque structure type — which could be declared using `struct Opaque;` — and passing that type to your functions.  Then attempts to pass `struct tm *` or `int *` or `char *` will cause a compilation warning.  Or use a fully defined structure type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help but feel that it would be cleaner to use a straight-forward structure to achieve your 'double VLA' structure type.  More or less like this:

```
// desired representation:
// uint64_t N_first;
// int32_t first[N_first];
// uint64_t N_second;
// double second[N_second];

#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct DoubleVLA
{
    uint64_t  N_first;
    int32_t  *first;
    uint64_t  N_second;
    double   *second;
    //double    align_32[];     // Ensures alignment on 32-bit
};

extern struct DoubleVLA *alloc_DoubleVLA(uint64_t n1, uint64_t n2);

struct DoubleVLA *alloc_DoubleVLA(uint64_t n1, uint64_t n2)
{
    struct DoubleVLA *dv = malloc(sizeof(*dv) + n1 * sizeof(dv->first) + n2 * sizeof(dv->second));
    if (dv != 0)
    {
        dv->N_first = n1;
        dv->N_second = n2;
        if (alignof(dv->second) >= alignof(dv->first))
        {
            dv->second = (double *)((char *)dv + sizeof(*dv));
            dv->first  = (int32_t *)((char *)dv + sizeof(*dv) + n2 * sizeof(dv->second));
        }
        else
        {
            dv->first  = (int32_t *)((char *)dv + sizeof(*dv));
            dv->second = (double *)((char *)dv + sizeof(*dv) + n1 * sizeof(dv->first));
        }
    }
    return dv;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct DoubleVLA *dv = alloc_DoubleVLA(UINT64_C(11), UINT64_C(32));
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < dv->N_first; i++)
        dv->first[i] = i * 100 + rand() % 100;
    for (uint64_t j = 0; j < dv->N_second; j++)
        dv->second[j] = j * 1000.0 + (rand() % 100000) / 100.0;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < dv->N_first; i++)
        printf("%.2" PRIu64 " = %12" PRId32 "\n", i, dv->first[i]);
    for (uint64_t j = 0; j < dv->N_second; j++)
        printf("%.2" PRIu64 " = %12.2f\n", j, dv->second[j]);
    free(dv);
    return 0;
}
```

Even on a 32-bit platform, there should be enough padding at the end of the structure to make its size such that it will be appropriately aligned for an array of `double` immediately after the structure and an array of `int32_t` after that.  However, there would be unnecessary padding that could be avoided by putting the two sizes first and the two pointers last in the structure.  That isn't a problem on a 64-bit platform.  The optional `align_32` VLA assumes that the alignment requirement of `int32_t` is not greater than the alignment requirement of `double`; it would ensure that the structure is padded correctly, even if there was some weird alignment restrictions or requirements.  It would be possible to provide a static assertion that the constraints are met.

The `alignof` material is from C11; it allows you to work with two types with different alignment requirements and automatically selects the better layout (more stringently aligned array before less stringent one).

With this organization, there's no need for a functional interface to the sections of the structure.  Direct access is simple and readily comprehended.

Comment: I like this, thank you for writing it up. I'm not sure whether caching the address lookup in pointers is worthwhile, but putting the fixed fields in a struct then allocating the struct + enough space for the arrays cuts out a lot of boilerplate. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing tedious ...

```
size_t offset_of_x = offsetof(equivalent, x);
size_t offset_of_y = offsetof(equivalent, y);
size_t offset_of_foo = offsetof(equivalent, foo);
size_t offset_of_z = offsetof(equivalent, z);

char* memory = malloc(sizeof(equivalent));
double* x    = offset_of_x   + memory;
char* y      = offset_of_y   + memory;
int32_t* foo = offset_of_foo + memory;
double* z    = offset_of_z   + memory;
free(memory);
```

And yes, this is perfectly legal.

/edit (after your edit):

Instead of using this representation:

```
struct fake_your_version {
    uint64_t N_first;
    int32_t first[N_first];
    uint64_t N_second;
    double second[N_second];
};
```

You should consider using either this representation:

```
struct fake_alternative_1 {
    uint64_t size; // max over all num[i]
    uint64_t num[2]; // num[0] being for first, num[1] being for second
    struct {
        int32_t first;
        double second;
    } entry[num];
};
```

or this representation:

```
struct fake_alternative_2 {
    uint64_t num[2];
    void * data[2]; // separate malloc(num[i] * sizeof(whatever));
};
```

Because your approach will enforce moving of data on a size change of anything but the last array.

`fake_alternative_1` will also save one `malloc` (at the expense of padding bytes and lost memory if the array need to be different sizes).

Before you even consider doing this, you should really ask youself, wheather `malloc` is really **that** slow, that you **must** avoid it. Probably, whatever you're doing, something else than `malloc` is slowing you down (possibly, your attempts to save `malloc`s make you code even slower instead of faster).

(`fake_alternative_2` will just accept, that each array get's it's own `malloc`, but I guess, I'm not telling you anything new by giving you this alternative).

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew it was official, but actually it's there since C89 ...